# Scatter plot - how to do it

Tags: python, plot, scatter-plot

I would like to reproduce this plot in Python: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CRfn.png)
Any idea how to do this?

I tried to do a normal plt.scatter() but I can't draw this axes on the zero, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very general question... Using `plt.scatter()` is certainly a good option. Then just add the two lines to the plot (e.g. using [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline) and `axvline`).

Slightly adapting this [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-scatter-py):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# don't show right and top axis[![enter image description here][1]][1]
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.right'] = False
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.top'] = False

# some random data
N = 50
x = np.random.randint(-10, high=11, size=N, dtype=int)
y = np.random.randint(-10, high=11, size=N, dtype=int)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = (30 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 15 point radii

# creating a vertical and a horizontal line
plt.axvline(x=0, color='grey', alpha=0.75, linestyle='-')
plt.axhline(y=0, color='grey', alpha=0.75, linestyle='-')
# scatter plot
plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot]